# How to lazy load a module from nrwl workspace libs folder?

Tags: angular, angular-cli, nrwl

I have a main app named `myapp`. I have configured my routes as below:

```
const routes: Routes = [
  { path: 'home', loadChildren: 'libs/home/home.module#HomeModule'},
  { path: 'admin', loadChildren: 'libs/admin/admin.module#AdminModule' },

  { path: '', redirectTo: '/home', pathMatch: 'full' },
  { path: '**', component: PageNotFoundComponent }
];
```

My `home` and `admin` are modules with its own routing and are placed in `libs`. When I run my application my modules are not getting loaded. I guess this is simply a path issue.. can someone please guide me how to properly configure the lazy loading modules from the library folder in nrwl workspace?

Here is the error I get:

```
ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Cannot find module 'libs/home/home.module'.
Error: Cannot find module 'libs/home/home.module'.
    at eval (eval at ../../../../../apps/myapp/src/$$_lazy_route_resource lazy recursive (main.bundle.js:6), <anonymous>:5:9)
    at ZoneDelegate.invoke (webpack-internal:///../../../../zone.js/dist/zone.js:388)
```

**Note**: I updated my tsconfig.app.json and tslint.json as follows:
tslint.json

```
"nx-enforce-module-boundaries": [
      true,
      {
        "lazyLoad": [
          "home",
          "admin"
        ],
        "allow": []
      }
    ]
```

and tsconfig.app.json:

```
 "include": [
    "**/*.ts",
    /* add all lazy-loaded libraries here: "../../../libs/my-lib/index.ts" */
    "../../../libs/home/index.ts",
    "../../../libs/admin/index.ts"    
  ],
```

thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

https://nrwl.io/nx/guide-nx-workspace#create-an-angular-module-lib

ng generate lib mymodule --routing 
    --lazy --parentModule=apps/myapp/src/myapp.module.ts

Comment: This answer gives a command that *creates a new lib* that will be lazy-loaded by some single app that is specified at the time of creation.  It doesn't really answer the question of how to lazy-load *already-existing* libs (which might need to be lazily loaded by more than one app).  Expansion of this answer would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Expansion would be especially helpful in my case, because the command given in the current answer doesn't result in my `app.module.ts` file being modified in any way.

Comment: The link is dead!

Comment: @AlexPeters I find that the best way to learn nx is to create what I'm creating in an empty project, see the difference and apply it to my existing project.

Answer (score 1):

With Angular v8 loading your lazy-loaded libraries works this way:

```
{ path: 'home', loadChildren: () => import('@yourprefix/home').then(m => m.HomeModule) },
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar error. I didn't fully understand the reasons, *so following are my assumptions*:

For lazy loading you should do:

1. Export all lazy modules in **distinct** `index.ts` files. You should
   not import those files;
2. Add references to those `index.ts` files in app-level `tsconfig.app.json`. Pay attention - not in root `tsconfig.json`, but in `app/tsconfig.app.json`;
3. Perhaps you should do `RouterModule.forChild(routes)` in your lazy lib's `lib.module.ts`;
4. Make sure you **do not import lazy modules** anywhere, and don't import `index.ts` that exports lazy modules;

Comment: Can you please expand on what "distinct `index.ts` files" means in this instance?  Distinct per lib?  Should there be multiple `index.ts` files for one lib if that lib contains multiple modules to be lazy-loaded?

Comment: I meant distinct per lib

Answer (score 0):

If you had forgot add parameter --parentModule when create your lib, you can fix this by adding your lib into 
apps/yourapp/tsconfig.app.json file into you app directory and add you module to

```
"include": ["**/*.ts", "../../libs/auth/src/index.ts", "../../libs/your-libname/src/index.ts"]
```

and in app.module.ts

```
{
path: 'mypath',
loadChildren: '@workspace/your-libname#YourLibnameModule'
}
```